# mysql queries are buffering on server with NodeJs and Redis

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis

Our app is using NodeJS with Redis and MySQL on Elastic Beanstalk and RDS.
The issue occurs randomly, when a user places an order, insert queries are generated and the user can see the order in his app (connected with Redis). The same order does not show up in the admin panel (web) which directly connects to MySQL. I can see the insert queries being executed in general logs, but there is no data in the tables corresponding to that.

I have rebooted the Redis server to check if the app is picking data from Redis buffer, but the order placed was there in the app and when I checked the DB after reboot all the missing order were now in the tables.

I am accessing the DB via MySQL benchmark. There is no bottleneck in any of the services. I am wondering if the query is there in general logs why there is no data in tables and how they have reappeared later. How can I debug this?

Comment: It sounds like your app isn't consistently committing transactions.  New rows generally would be invisible until the commit occurs.  Starting the next transaction implicitly commits the previous one.

Comment: Is there anyway i can trace or debug uncommitted  transactions in nodejs. Also how can I make sure that the transactions are committed after query execution.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;` will show you any transactions that are currently running.  If you see a transaction there for very long, it's likely the one you're looking for.  Modify your code to log the connection ID of each db connection -- found in `connection.threadId` or the result of `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()`.  This is the same connection identifier found in the `innodb_trx` table and `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`.